# Date not working in Typescript but working in browser console

Tags: angular, date, typescript, angular-cli

I get this error  **Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target**. when I try to do this in my TypeScript file in Angular2.

```
console.log(Date(this.field.sowing_date));
```

If I execute the same thing in the Chrome Debugger I don't get any problem.

Do you know what is?

I am using:

"@angular/core": "^2.4.0"
"@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",

Comment: You are not executing it. That is a type checking error. The code will still run.

Comment: Anyway, `Date` called as a function without an argument simply ignores it. That is why TypeScript is warning you that something is wrong. You have a bug. The code will always return a string representation of the current Date and Time

Comment: @AluanHaddad is with an argument this.field.sowing_date?

Comment: The argument is ignored at runtime. TypeScript raises an error for arity mismatches. Did you mean `new Date(this.field.sowing_date)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a parameter to `Date` when you don't use it as a constructor (without `new`):

**In JavaScript:**

```
Date(); // returns current date as string
Date("1/1/2017"); // ignores the parameter and returns the current date as string
```

TypeScript rightfully complains because `Date(param)` is not a valid way to call `Date`.

You can use `Date` in TypeScript like:

```
let currentDateAsString : string = Date(); // if you want the current date string
let parsedDate: Date = new Date(this.field.sowing_date); // if you want to parse it.
```

MDN documentation on `Date` which explains the ways `Date` can be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date